# Idiom for Initializing UINavigationItem

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib, uinavigationitem

Since `UIViewController` navigationItem outlets are deprecated (yes, I'm a bit behind), what is the correct idiom specifying the elements of a `UINavigationItem`?

I've seen several approaches suggested, but none are entirely clear to me:

1. "Embed the navigation item in the view controller" in the view controller's XIB.
2. Initialize the navigation item's properties in code, with from-scratch values.
3. Create an outlet for the navigation controller in the view controller, wire up a navigation item in the view controller's XIB, and use its properties to initialize the (actual) navigation item's properties in code.

[It isn't clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285440/associating-a-navigation-item-with-a-controller-in-a-xib) to me how to "embed" the navigation item (simply adding it as a child of the view controller in IB has no effect); and it isn't clear to me which of these approaches is better, or, for that matter, where (in what method) to do 2 or 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) If controller is *created* in XIB you can drop `UINavigationItem` on it and tweak this item - it will work. For example when you're defining `UINavigationControler` in XIB you can put some controller inside as root view controller. So you can have `UINavigationItem` for this controller in XIB.

2) If controller *loads it's view* from XIB (it was created by `alloc` and then `init` or `initWithNibName:bundle:`) it's presented in XIB only as `File's Owner` which doesn't support `UINavigationItem` in it. In this case you should configure navigation item in code (I do it in `viewDidLoad` usually). There is no need to create it, it's already there in `navigtionItem` property of your controller

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Price List";
```

Maybe it's possible to make outlet for navigation item but I wouldn't recommend this. Apple declared such outlet obsolete for a reason. I remember discussing this with co-worker one day, but I forgot what it was (it was obvious then).

Comment: So, if I understand 1 correctly: If the controller to which I want to attache a `UINavigationItem` is the child of another entity in a XIB (e.g. a `UINavigationController`) then I can "embed" the `UINavigationItem` as a child and it will work. _However_, if the controller is the owner of a XIB, there's no way to attach a `UINavigationItem` in XIB. If so, that's odd, since it means that while you could potentially use IB to specify a `UINavigationItem` for the initial view in a navigation controller, all the rest would have to be specified in code.

Answer (score 1):

On our project we have a requirement to make UI be as customizable from IB as possible.
So, I add UINavigationItem to xib, configure it, link it as outlet to my custom UIViewController subclass, and then copy all properties at runtime with method added to UIViewController using category:

```
- (void)setNavigationItemPropertiesFromOtherItem:(UINavigationItem *)navItem 
{
    // WORKAROUND: we can't link UINavigationItem to UIViewController from IB, and navigationItem property in UIViewController is readonly
    self.navigationItem.title = navItem.title;
    self.navigationItem.prompt = navItem.prompt;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = navItem.hidesBackButton;
    if (navItem.backBarButtonItem != nil) 
    {
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = navItem.backBarButtonItem;
    }
    if (navItem.leftBarButtonItem != nil)
    {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navItem.leftBarButtonItem;
    }
    if (navItem.rightBarButtonItem != nil)
    {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    }
    if (navItem.titleView != nil)
    {
        self.navigationItem.titleView = navItem.titleView;
    }
}
```

This workaround also allows to link bar button items to UINavigationItem using IB.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same requirement and I adopted your method. It works.